# JavaScript Regex Zipcode validation issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex for validating 5 digit zipcode. But it is not working.

```
var zipcode_regex = /[\d]{5,5}/;
if (zipcode_regex.test($.trim($('#zipcode').val())) == false)
alert('invalid zipcode');
```

I am also using jQuery in the code snippet.

Comment: *But it is not working*. What is happening and what do you expect to happen? Please provide some example input and output and be more precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex also matches if there is a five-digit *substring* somewhere inside your string. If you want to validate "only exactly five digits, nothing else", then you need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your regex:

```
var zipcode_regex = /^\d{5}$/;
if (zipcode_regex.test($.trim($('#zipcode').val())) == false)
    alert('invalid zipcode');
```

And you can get that more easily:

```
if (!(/^\s*\d{5}\s*$/.test($('#zipcode').val()))) {
    alert('invalid zipcode');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex just matches exactly 5 digits:

```
/^\d{5}$/
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference and *why* it does help?

Comment: Oh, I just simplified the regex, maybe I should have written it at the comment section. But I don't think the OP's problem has anything to do with this regex, this regex just matches exactly 5 digits. It may be because of something self.

Comment: Well, we don't know what is the OP's problem. But I think you are right. You need to anchor the expression with `^` and `$`. Otherwise, `\d{5}` matches any string with **at least** 5 digits. That's what I was aiming at ;)

Comment: @Tim: It's different since it is anchored... I guess that is the problem, but until the OP clarifies, we don't know for sure.

Comment: @FelixKling: Whoops. I honestly didn't see the anchors when I first read Neevek's answer. If I had, I wouldn't have written mine.

Comment: @Tim: Well, you provided the missing explanation :)

Comment: The anchors were added in **1** second after I posted my original answer. I think it was in that 1 second that you had read my original answer. So it's OK.